# Many To Many order by time it got added to post

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Entity 
public class Post{
        
   private Long id;
        
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "tag_posts", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private Set<Tag> hashtags= new LinkedHashSet<>();
    
}
```

Hello I would like to sort hashtags by right order they got added in to post, is anything like this possible?

Or would I just change type to List? Wouldnt this affect performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to retrieve Post along with the tags but you want tags in the order it got added to the Post.
You can use @OrderBy annotation to get the list of tags while retrieving.

```java
@Entity 
public class Post{
        
   private Long id;
        
   @OrderBy(value="orderField")
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "tag_posts", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private Set<Tag> hashtags= new LinkedHashSet<>();
    
}
```

If you want to create a column in the join table which will keep the same order you can use @OrderByColumn("orderField")